# php include not working in my html document

Tags: php, html

I am using php include command in an html document for the first time and its not working for some reason.

The reason why i am using php include is because i link several css, jquery and jv files to my html document.

I put all those links to make my other 60 html documents. and if i have to change or add any link to it. it will be hard to change it in all 60 documents.

so i used php command like this on the very top of my html document.

```
<?php
include("http://www.omenaa.ws/html/scripts.html"); 
?>
```

and this is what i put in scripts.html file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type=
  "text/javascript">
</script>
  <script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
  <link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type=
  "text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.omenaa.ws/css/slider.css" />
  <script src="http://omenaa.ws/js/jquery.fitvids.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
  <script src="http://api.html5media.info/1.1.5/html5media.min.js" type=
  "text/javascript">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  // <![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            nextSelector: '#slider-next',
            prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
            infiniteLoop: false,
            adaptiveHeight:true,
            video:true,
            nextText: 'Next &nbsp;-&nbsp; I am done!',
            prevText: 'I need to go back'
        });
    });
    // ]]>
  </script>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: do you get an error? Do you see the PHP code? Is your server configured to use PHP?

Comment: http://www.omenaa.ws/html/scripts.html doesnt seem to have any content...

Comment: i am testing it locally, without xxamp

Comment: Also, "the very top of my **html** document" - you should be using a .php file, not a .html file.

Comment: omenaa.ws/html/scripts.html doesnt have content, it has linked scripts

Comment: @user2540648 if youre running on windows, include may not work for URL's http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Are you executing this from `.php` or `.html` file? if it's `.php` you need to use an `AddType` in your `.htaccess file` that tells the server to execute php code inside of html documents, such as, `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

Comment: @Danny you can use .html file depending how you have your htaccess rules set up

Comment: **I am testing it locally without xampp** *sigh*

Comment: @SethMcClaine I know that; but the chances are the OP hasn't done this.

Comment: Try with a `.php` extension and see if you get the same result.

Comment: hold on, i will try to use .php extension

Comment: Ummm.... if you aren't using a server of some description, how will PHP know to run your script?

Comment: i tried it with the .php extension on xampp, it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i am testing it locally, without xxamp`

Your computer cannot execute PHP without an engine to interpret it. There is no built in support on your computer, you will need a server to interpret the code and deliver it to the browser accordingly.

**EDIT**

By default, a Xamp installation will not attempt to execute php code inside of .html files, you will be required to enable support for it. One of the easiest ways is to open a `.htaccess` file and simply do:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

This will tell your server to interper html documents like they would php documents, allowing for the php code to execute.

Otherwise, simply rename  the file from `.html` to `.php` and it'll work.

Comment: do you have any other solution?

Comment: ok, i tried putting it in my .htaccess file, when i open the .php file, it gave me these warnings.

`Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\omenaa.ws\Day 01.php on line 2

Warning: include(http://www.omenaa.ws/html/scripts.html): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\omenaa.ws\Day 01.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://www.omenaa.ws/html/scripts.html' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\omenaa.ws\Day 01.php on line 2`

Comment: @user2540648 Then simply `allow_url_include`, either in your `php.ini` file, or within `.htaccess` by doing `php_flag allow_url_include on`. Of course, there's a reason it's disabled, so you should really ensure that's the file you want to include. Otherwise, you could land yourself in a world of hurt. Also, you could use `file_get_contents`, or `curl`, if it's your own environment, you can enable `CORS` aka `cross origin resource sharing` and limit it to certain sites / ip addresses, etc.

Comment: @user2540648 you need to refer to the answer below.

Comment: so far i have added these to .htaccess
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`
`php_flag allow_url_include on`
`file_get_contents`

Comment: @user2540648 What? no.. you just need to do `php_flag allow_url_include`, you do not need `file_get_contents`, that is a php function.

Comment: ok, i removed it. still the same result, want me to test it out on my site instead of xampp?

Comment: lol, i got it working when i uploaded it to the site and refered it locally. Thanks alot

Comment: @user2540648 this is more suitable for the right answer hope you will check this one instead of the other one.

Comment: its hard to decide! I think you helped me more than other person did.

Answer (score -2):

including urls requires extra permissions - you are trusting the author of that remote website not to put nasty php code in... the setting you are looking for is allow_url_include, and it is 0 (off) by default.

If the file is local, you should make the include refer to the local file, not the url.

Comment: umm! i am the owner of the site. and the reason why i didn't refer it locally because i am working on it on my comp. then i will transfer it on my site.

Comment: why the dv? this is the problem. you can't use url wrappers with `include`

Comment: what's URL wrappers? HTTP:// ??

Comment: the "include" command was designed to include local files. URL Wrappers allow you to use, under the right circumstances, URLs the same as you woul local files.